# videos json not found in facebook android sdk

Tags: android, facebook

Today,I use the facebook android sdk to develope app.
I want to get my facebook's the list of videos,but I get it as follow.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/me/videos

{"data":[]}
I find the request command "/{user-id}/videos",but it can't get the useful data.it's empty.I don't know how to solve it.

ps:In my facebook homepage,I have two public videos.

Comment: what permissions have you granted your app?

Comment: I have added the all permissions.